# Ecto 2.0 + MySQL: cleaning fixtures in tests

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am using Ecto 2.0 along with MySQL in a Elixir Phoenix project. 
According to Ecto2.0 [documentation](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/04/ecto-2-0-0-rc-is-out/), *MySQL does not support concurrent tests* so I guess I should use use `ExUnit.Case` instead of use `ExUnit.Case, async: true` so that tests don't run concurrently.

In my particular case, in my tests I am inserting models in database by means of fixtures, and once tests are done, models inserted by fixtures still remain in database (models inserted by the tested code itself get cleaned). I want to remove the models inserted by fixture. If I do:

If I do:

```
ExUnit.Case

setup do
  on_exit fn ->
    Repo.delete_all(ModelA)
    Repo.delete_all(ModelB)
  end
end
```

I get:

```
    ** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.277.0>, {:checkout, #Reference<0.0.1.1885>, true, 15000}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) shutdown: "owner #PID<0.276.0> exited with: shutdown"
stacktrace:
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/ownership/proxy.ex:32: DBConnection.Ownership.Proxy.checkout/2
```

Then, if I do:

```
ExUnit.Case, async: true

setup do
  on_exit fn ->
    Repo.delete_all(ModelA)
    Repo.delete_all(ModelB)
  end
end
```

it works and fixture data gets cleaned in database. But if I specify `ExUnit.Case, async: true`, when running all tests, I'm going to have problems because tests runnig concurrently on MySQl.

Comment: Where are you inserting the fixtures from?

Comment: Fixtures are defined in a module in test/support and they are inserted in test database. Tests are using and working with these inserted fixtures, but they don't get automatically cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have omitted some of your error message. I can't say for sure, but a common error with ecto2 is ownership getting mixed up. With ecto2 there's now process ownership mechanism, which tracks which transaction belongs to which process, so that concurrent stateful tests can work.

However, you need to *tell* ecto that mapping. `on_exit` runs in a separate process from the caller, so it tries to access the database when ecto doesn't know which transaction owns it, an error is thrown.

You may need to tell ecto (in your `setup` block) to set the mode of the sandbox to allow any process to access the database in a shared transaction. Since you're using MySQL, there's no use managing ownership manually since you'll never be running concurrent database tests anyway, so it'd be best to just turn on the shared mode for everything.

You can do so with this:

```
setup do
  Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Perf.Repo, {:shared, self()})
end
```

I would paste some of the relevant parts of the docs into this post but I wouldn't do it justice, the documentation on this part of ecto is extremely helpful, detailed, and useful.
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.html